# How do you define a stored procedure in java?

Tags: java, c#, oracle

I've worked with web on asp.net C# defining connections with the following structure

```
try
{
    sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(dbConnectionString);
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_Test", sqlConnection);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtId.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = txtName.Text;
    sqlConnection.Open();
    return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlConnection.Close();
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("SQL MESSAGE Error" + ex.Message.ToString());
    return 0;
}
```

...but I'm looking for its equivalent in java. The application I'm working on it is only local. I just need to connect my netbeans, the java IDE I'll use, to my ORACLE Database. The version of the database is Oracle 11g release 2. Thanks for the help!

Comment: [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html) tutorial should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Netbeans is an IDE which is completely unrelated to your database operation. Please, clarify what you want to do.

Comment: @Holger, sorry for the misunderstood. I just want to know the structure of what I have to code in order to access to my stored procedure  from my java application developed in Neatbeans. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @npinti thanks I think that's the one I was looking for!